# BufferedImage is automatically updated when int-array representing its raster is updated

Tags: java, raster

I'm following a tutorial to expand my knowledge, but the tutor is sometimes of the mindset that some things need not be explained.

take a look at this code:

```
private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
private int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

someMethod() {
  for (int i=0; i<pixels.length; i++) {
    pixels[i] = i;
  }
  g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
}
```

I paint on a Canvas and to my big surprise this will paint colors from black to blue. I wonder how to access/modify colors red and green (since the "pixels" is an array of single integers). if I replace RGB with BGR, this color will be red instead. But that's a sidenote. **EDIT**: to paint green and red use bitshift operators `<< and |`. for instance: `int greenColor = 255<<16;` or `int greenAndRed = 255<<16 | 255<<8;` **EDIT-END**

The one major puzzle here is why anything is painted at all. How does assigning values to the pixels array update image? (I don't understand the field declaration at all. What the array is initiated to, that is). But my knowledge of Java tells me that is irrelevant. It is an ordinary int-array, with ordinary ints. Can someone tell me what's going on?

**EDIT**
Question has been resolved. It is actually no big surprise that the image data changes at all since arrays are not immutable like the other simple data-types.

Comment: The system.out.println does return true, if you change pixel[1] to pixels[1]

Comment: @arynaq Oh yeah, sorry. That was a typo. The question was based on a fallacy on my part. I could have sworn that arrays were immutable. I'll just remove that part of the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The raster is the backing datamodel of the image. The `int[] pixels` you are getting here is a reference to that backing data. Changing a value in the pixel array is actually changing the value of the backing data, immediately visible in the image.

Comment: Well, it might not be immediately visible as you soon as you change the array - but as soon as you draw the image, yes.

Comment: I was kind of afraid the answer would be like this. Because the only thing I can say again is: "Why?". It goes against my understanding of variables in Java. How is that connection made between the array and the image?

Comment: I have worked with data-models when messing around with Swing.Jtable, and it surprised me that whenever I changed a value in my application, the model would automatically call its "valueAt"-method to update the table". But I never tell this image that it must be painted with "pixels".

Comment: The connection is not made by us, it is already there via the datamodel, we are just creating a reference to that model and changing some values, the raster decides how it implements the int[] of pixels.

Comment: The difference is, that in Swing (and most other UI toolkits), the view does not contain the data directly, so some sort of event needs to be raised for the view to update. And then again, maybe it is not so different: You are still calling drawImage for the display to be updated, it is just not as a reaction to an event.

Comment: Wow. I'm extremely shocked to realize that all of this was based on my assumption that arrays were imutable. I am just very, very confused. Sorry guys for wasting your time.